# selectively render sections of a custom component

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

I want to selectively render the 2 "Changes" sections below if the {!c.any_changes__c == No}. is there a way to group it together in a parent element without messing up the CSS or table?

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="EmailTemplateHelper"> 
    <apex:attribute id="oppId" assignTo="{!oppId}" name="opportunityIDFromEmail" type="String" description="The Opporunity's SF ID"/>    
    <br/>
    <apex:repeat var="c" value="{!Checklists}">
        <table class="maintable">
             <td class="section">
                <table width="100%" >    <tr><td BGCOLOR="#2d97cc" ALIGN="center">Information</td></tr> </table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">Policy Number:</td>   <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.Policy_number__c}</td> </tr></table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">Checklist:</td> <td class="sub_section_data"> <a href="https://cs15.salesforce.com/{!c.id}">{!c.name}</a></td></tr></table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">Opportunity:</td>     <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.Opportunity__r.name}</td> </tr></table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">Any changes?:</td>    <td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.Any_changes__c}</td> </tr></table>

                <table width="100%" >    <tr><td BGCOLOR="#2d97cc" ALIGN="center">Changes</td></tr> </table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">change 1:</td><td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.ch1__c}</td> </tr></table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">change 2:</td><td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.ch2__c}</td> </tr></table>

                <table width="100%" >    <tr><td BGCOLOR="#2d97cc" ALIGN="center">Changes 2</td></tr> </table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">change 3:</td><td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.ch3__c}</td> </tr></table>
                <table class="sub_section"> <tr>  <td class="mysub_section_label">change 4:</td><td class="sub_section_data"> {!c.ch4__c}</td> </tr></table>
              </td>  
        </table>     
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>                     
     </apex:repeat>  
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr style="display: {!IF(ISBLANK(Field__c), 'none', 'table-row')};">
<td>Content of your cell</td>
</tr>
```

try above code

or

you could use apex variable to control rendering of table row

```
<apex:variable var="v" value="" rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(TheField__c))}">
<tr>
<td><apex:outputLabel rendered="if field is not blank"><td> 
</tr>
</apex:variable>
```

Comment: Or, just wrap the changes tables inside an outputText and conditionally render them that way.